# Get N terms with top TFIDF scores for each documents in Lucene (PyLucene)

Tags: java, python, lucene, tf-idf

I am currently using PyLucene but since there is no documentation for it, I guess a solution in Java for Lucene will also do (but if anyone has one in Python it would be even better).

I am working with scientific publications and for now, I retrieve the keywords of those. However, for some documents there are simply no keywords. An alternative to this would be to get N words (5-8) with the highest TFIDF scores.

I am not sure how to do it, and also **when**. By when, I mean : Do I have to tell Lucene at the stage of indexing to compute these values, of it is possible to do it when searching the index.

What I would like to have for each query would be something like this :

```
Query Ranking

Document1, top 5 TFIDF terms, Lucene score (default TFIDF)
Document2,     "       "    ,   "         "
...
```

What would also be possible is to first retrieve the ranking for the query, and then compute the top 5 TFIDF terms for each of these documents.

Does anyone have an idea how shall I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a bit in the mailing list, I ended up having what I was looking for.

Here is the method I came up with :

```
def getTopTFIDFTerms(docID, reader):
    termVector = reader.getTermVector(docID, "contents");
    termsEnumvar = termVector.iterator(None)
    termsref = BytesRefIterator.cast_(termsEnumvar)
    tc_dict = {}                     # Counts of each term
    dc_dict = {}                     # Number of docs associated with each term
    tfidf_dict = {}                  # TF-IDF values of each term in the doc
    N_terms = 0
    try:
        while (termsref.next()):
            termval = TermsEnum.cast_(termsref)
            fg = termval.term().utf8ToString()       # Term in unicode
            tc = termval.totalTermFreq()             # Term count in the doc

            # Number of docs having this term in the index
            dc = reader.docFreq(Term("contents", termval.term())) 
            N_terms = N_terms + 1 
            tc_dict[fg]=tc
            dc_dict[fg]=dc
    except:
        print 'error in term_dict'

    # Compute TF-IDF for each term
    for term in tc_dict:
        tf = tc_dict[term] / N_terms
        idf = 1 + math.log(N_DOCS_INDEX/(dc_dict[term]+1)) 
        tfidf_dict[term] = tf*idf

    # Here I get a representation of the sorted dictionary
    sorted_x = sorted(tfidf_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    # Get the top 5 
    top5 = [i[0] for i in sorted_x[:5]] # replace 5 by TOP N
```

I am not sure why I have to cast the `termsEnum` as a `BytesRefIterator`, I got this from a thread in the mailing list which can be found [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-pylucene-dev/201402.mbox/%3CCAPJ5eE-WM78oZronESNAcurM3azp=ho2XHv-HS4aVr_S5V18Yg@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 3):

If a field is [indexed](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html#indexed()), document frequencies can be retrieved with [getTerms](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiFields.html#getTerms(org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader,%20java.lang.String)).  If a field has [stored term vectors](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html#storeTermVectors()), term frequencies can be retrieved with [getTermVector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector(int,%20java.lang.String)).

I also suggest looking at [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.html), which uses tf*idf to create a query similar to the document, from which you can extract the terms.

And if you'd like a more pythonic interface, that was my motivation for [lupyne](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupyne/):

```
from lupyne import engine
searcher = engine.IndexSearcher(<filepath>)
df = dict(searcher.terms(<field>, counts=True))
tf = dict(searcher.termvector(<docnum>, <field>, counts=True))
query = searcher.morelikethis(<docnum>, <field>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I ended up getting what I wanted in Python. I will post my answer so other people struggling with PyLucene can see it!